# Delayed charges on card that has been cancelled

Tags: credit-card, mastercard

I had Mastercard X that had been used to reserve a week long car rental a couple months ago.

Then, a month ago, the card was replaced with Mastercard Y because I was determined to be eligible for a better, premium card.

However, a delayed charge was applied to card Y by the car rental company. I am just curious as to how they were able to charge this card since they only had details/authorization for card X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vendor had your card info, name, and a transaction code for the reservation.

If you kept the same banking company and just changed from credit card program x to credit card program y, the banking company would have been able to link the two accounts. If you had switched banking companies there would have been no linkage.

This is exactly how you would hope it would work. You weren't looking for a second card, you wanted to use your history to transfer to a better card. Of course if the new card number was being issued due to possible fraud on the old card you would hope that the charges wouldn't move seamlessly to the new account, because that would allow potential fraudulent items to attach to the new card.